# Is it possible to update MPAndroidChart with new data?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using android MPAndroidChart
I am trying to update my MPAndroidChart but I get an error
MPAndroidChart How can I erase existing data and draw new data?
Each time you update, the value of xLabel changes.
Can I update the new data by changing the value of the xLabel?

```
chart.invalidate();
chart.clear();
chartMonth.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(null);
```

I've tried the above

```
final ArrayList<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<lastDayOfMonth;i++)
{
    xLabel.add(String.valueOf(i+1));
}

XAxis xAxis = chartMonth.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter()
{
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value)
    {
        return xLabel.get((int) value); //An error occurs here 
    }
});
```

Comment: what errors????

Comment: error of IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index of bound error occurs when the length of YAxis value is not equal to the length of XAxis length.

You can update the new data.